# can't display page when i run on local server

Tags: javascript, performance, frontend

Every time I try to run my code on a local server, my laptop gets so slow and warm and the page won't display as shown below.

[image]

The source code looks like I am in an infinite loop but can't figure out what's wrong.

```
deck.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const clickTarget = event.target;

  if (clickTarget.classList.contains('card') &&
    !clickTarget.classList.contains('match') && toggledCards.length < 2 &&
    !toggledCards.includes(clickTarget)) {
    toggleCard(clickTarget);
    addToggleCard(clickTarget);
    if (toggledCards.length === 2) {
      checkForMatch(clickTarget);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger. Chrome, Firefox and IE all have a built-in debugger.

Comment: @dustytrash how i would debug it if its not working at all!

Comment: You should be able to press f12 and place a breakpoint in the Javascript code. You can then load it line by line

Comment: @dustytrash found it , it was different function thank you

Answer (score 0):

99% times when cpu goes crazy and that pop up shows. It's because of a endless loop.

Probably one of the called functions, makes a click somewhere.
To avoid it you have to debug the functions like @dustytrash advised.